# IIS changes the physical path to application it self

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I have set two websites in my IIS 8.5. I have one for production version and one for development (need this for the team work purposes). The structure is simple. Website is simple static page using BackboneJS and API calls to get all the data. All virtual paths and applications were set at the beginning manually by my self. For some reason some API calls didn't worked in dev site. I found out the physical path to the API project has changed. Do you have any idea, where can be the problem? Actually some of my collegues face this issue too.

Only think that cames to my mind is that when bdebugging the API, I use "Attach to process" in Visual Studio, where I connect to the correct IIS process - w3wp.exe with user name IIS APPPOOL\Dev or IIS APPPOOL\Prod according to the site I'm debugging.

Nevertheless I don't think the path should change itself. Where can be the problem? Does anyone have any idea how to prevent this strange behaviour?